# How to rename suffix of all files in listbox?

Tags: vb.net, listbox, rename, suffix

I have a windows form that contains two list boxes and two tool strip labels (buttons).
[image]

On pressing the first button (Open folder), a file browser opens and you can select multiple files, these are then loaded into listbox 1 (ListFilesLoaded), now what I want to do is display converted file names in Listbox 2 (ConvertedNames). for example...

- apple_001.jpg > apple_Ambrosia.jpg
- apple_002.jpg > apple_Melba.jpg
- apple_003.jpg > apple_Granny.jpg

Then press my second button (Rename Files) to save the renamed files in their original directory (removing the old files / names).

So far I have gotten the loading listbox1 (ListFilesLoaded) working fine. I'm just not sure how to go about changing their display names in listbox 2 (ConvertedNames) and saving them out as the new file names.

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
Private openFile As OpenFileDialog 'window to open files

Private Sub ToolStripLabel1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripLabel1.Click
    Try
        openFile = New OpenFileDialog
        openFile.Title = "Select files."
        openFile.CheckFileExists = True
        openFile.Multiselect = True
        openFile.RestoreDirectory = False

        If openFile.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            openFile.SafeFileNames.Count()
            For i As Integer = 0 To openFile.SafeFileNames.Count() - 1
                ListFilesLoaded.Items.Add(openFile.SafeFileNames(i))
                ConvertedNames.Items.Add(openFile.SafeFileNames(i))
            Next

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

    End Try


End Sub

Private Sub ToolStripLabel2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripLabel2.Click

End Sub
```

So essentially I think I need something like...

```
If ConvertedNames.Items.string.contains "_001" then
   ConvertedNames.Items.string = ConvertedNames.Items.string -4 + _Ambrosia
else if
   ConvertedNames.Items.string.contains "_002" then
   ConvertedNames.Items.string = ConvertedNames.Items.string -4 + _Melba
else if
   ConvertedNames.loaded.name.contains "_003" then
   ConvertedNames.Items.string = ConvertedNames.Items.string -4 + _Granny
End If
```

When it comes to the saving names part, I have no idea at all.

Thanks for taking the time too look.

Comment: Where are the new names coming from? Are they stored somewhere or are you entering them manually at the time?

Comment: The new names will always be the same, so I wanted to hard code them, there is a total of 12 images that I get and they are always preceded with 001,002,003 etc. These will always change to the same word.

So...
001 will always become Ambrosia
002 will always become Melba
and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the names of your controls to match my test program.

I used a `List(Of Tuple(Of String, String)` to store the path and file name of the original files. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/tuples and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple?view=net-5.0 Without named items, the Tuple elements are referred to as `Item1` for the first string and `Item2` as the second string. Since our method is small, I felt that naming the elements or using a structure or class was not necessary.

```
Item1 is the full path (with file name and extension)
Item2 is the file name only with extension
```

Next, we bind the list to the first list box setting the display and value members. Now we can loop through the list box. Remember that each item in the list box is a `Tuple(Of String, String)` and we can refer to its elements with `Item1` and `Item2`. We send the file name off to a function that returns the new file name

To actually change the file name on disk we can use the Visual Basic specific `FileIO.FileSystem.Rename` method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.renamefile?view=net-5.0 This method takes as parameters, the full path of the original file and the new file name.

Finally, the new name is added to the second list box.

The `GetNewName` function uses a `Select Case` and the `String.Replace` method to do the job.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-5.0

```
Private Sub ToolStripLabel1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripLabel1.Click
    Dim openFile = New OpenFileDialog
    openFile.Title = "Select files."
    openFile.CheckFileExists = True
    openFile.Multiselect = True
    openFile.RestoreDirectory = False

    If openFile.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim lstPathAndFile As New List(Of Tuple(Of String, String))
        For Each filePath In openFile.FileNames
            lstPathAndFile.Add(Tuple.Create(filePath, Path.GetFileName(filePath)))
        Next
        ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Item2"
        ListBox1.ValueMember = "Item1"
        ListBox1.DataSource = lstPathAndFile
        For Each t As Tuple(Of String, String) In ListBox1.Items
            Dim NewName = GetNewName(t.Item2)
            FileIO.FileSystem.RenameFile(t.Item1, NewName)
            ListBox2.Items.Add(NewName)
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetNewName(OriginalFileName As String) As String
    Dim NewFileName As String = ""
    Select Case True
        Case OriginalFileName.Contains("001")
            NewFileName = OriginalFileName.Replace("001", "Ambrosia")
        Case OriginalFileName.Contains("002")
            NewFileName = OriginalFileName.Replace("002", "Melba")
        Case OriginalFileName.Contains("003")
            NewFileName = OriginalFileName.Replace("003", "Granny")
    End Select
    Return NewFileName
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Mary,

Thank you for this, it works brilliantly, I have split it to work over multiple buttons now and it's doing the job it's supposed to.

I do get one error though, after adding "ListFilesLoaded.Items.Clear()" to the open files button (so I can clear any open files and essentially select a new set of files to rename), the application errors when the button is pressed ("Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.").

I added this line of code just before the 'If' statement to open files.

Comment: @Oogle_doogleson I think you need to set `ListFilesLoaded.DataSource = Nothing` To clear the `List(Of T)` use the `.Clear` method.